# How can I trigger a keyframe when the user scrolls to a certain part of a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyframe

is it possible to detect where a user scrolls on a page to trigger a keyframe using pure javascript ?

```
    .animations {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: animations-keyframes 2s ease forwards;
    -webkit-animation: animations-keyframes 2s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes animations-keyframes {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animations-keyframes {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I want javascript to trigger this event when the user gets to a certain part of a page for example a content section. I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript, you could add the class `animations` to an element on `mouseenter` event and remove the class on `mouseleave`. Since you didn't mention jQuery, I will use simple JS, but I recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you plan on doing a bunch of DOM manipulation since it is easier to maintain.

EXAMPLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/z6xmuwse/2/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var el = document.getElementById("animation");

el.onmouseenter = function (){
    this.classList.add("animations");
};

el.onmouseleave = function (){
    this.classList.remove("animations");
};
```

---

However, you can also accomplish this using just CSS and the pseudo `:hover`.

EXAMPLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/z6xmuwse/3/

CSS:

```
.animations:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: animations-keyframes 2s ease forwards;
    -webkit-animation: animations-keyframes 2s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes animations-keyframes {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animations-keyframes {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you. I understand that jQuery can handle this problem more easy but it is required of me to do custom scripts. This helped a lot thanks

Answer (score 1):

Waypoints can be used to trigger events when scrolling to certain parts of a page.
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

In simple terms, event listeners are created for scroll events - The distance scrolled down the page and distance of the element from the top of the page are compared. Events are triggered if the user has scrolled beyond the element ( distance scrolled > distance of element from top of page )

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll go ahead and start investigating